# What is the difference between always and on failure for Kubernetes restart policy?

Tags: kubernetes, restart

The best source for restart policies in Kubernetes I have found is this:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy

But it only lists the possible `restartPolicy` values and does not explain them.

What is the difference between `Always` and `OnFailure`? Mustn't the thing fail before it can be restarted?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Always** means that the container will be restarted even if it exited with a zero exit code (i.e. successfully). This is useful when you don't care why the container exited, you just want to make sure that it is always running (e.g. a web server). This is the default.

**OnFailure** means that the container will only be restarted if it exited with a non-zero exit code (i.e. something went wrong). This is useful when you want accomplish a certain task with the pod, and ensure that it completes successfully - if it doesn't it will be restarted until it does.

**Never** means that the container will not be restarted regardless of why it exited.

These different restart policies basically map to the different controller types as you can see from `kubectl run --help`:

> --restart="Always": The restart policy for this Pod.  Legal values [Always, OnFailure, Never].  If set to 'Always' a deployment is created for this pod, if set to 'OnFailure', a job is created for this pod, if set to 'Never', a regular pod is created. For the latter two --replicas must be 1.  Default 'Always'

And the [pod user-guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pod-states/#restartpolicy):

> ReplicationController is only appropriate for pods with RestartPolicy = Always. Job is only appropriate for pods with RestartPolicy equal to OnFailure or Never.

Comment: Hello Pixel, can I understand that, If I use RS/deployment to create pods, I must set "RestartPolicy = Always" in yaml?

Comment: @JamesPei not really!!. There is nothing to set *RestartPolicy=_something_*. 

It is an imperative command. All you need to do is you need to create a separate resource like RS or Deployment in your resource-definition file.

Comment: When would a container with a web-server exit with a zero exit code? Are there any scenarios where this could happen?

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, simplier than the official documentation.

Comment: Update:
"If set to 'Always' a deployment is created for this pod, if set to 'OnFailure', a job is created for this pod, if set to 'Never', a regular pod is created. For the latter two --replicas must be 1. Default 'Always'"

This is not shown anymore in current kubernetes version 1.21 and is no longer valid. Deleting a pod that has set restart Always won't get brought back like a deployment, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a practical example:

```bash
kubectl run never --image=alpine --restart=Never  -- echo "Hello"
```

It will spin up a Pod that runs and terminates  **successfully** (`echo hello`) and will **never** be restarted, therefore the status will be completed.

[image]

```bash
kubectl run onfail --image=alpine --restart=OnFailure  -- echo "Hello"
```

It will spin up a Pod that runs and terminates **successfully** (will `echo hello`) therefore it will not be restarted, and the status will also completed:
[image]

```bash
kubectl run onfail1 --image=alpine --restart=OnFailure  -- exit 0
```

It will spin up a Pod that runs and terminates but with an **error** therefore it will be restarted, and the pod will be in CrashLoopBackOff:

[image]

```bash
kubectl run always --image=alpine --restart=Always  -- echo "Hello"
```

It will spin up a Pod that runs and terminates **successfully** (will `echo hello`), but it will **always** get restarted:
[image]

Using `Always` as a restart policy you might consider that it behaves like a `deployment` and using `OnFailure` as a restart policy it behaves like a `job`