# Disable Crashloop feature in Kubernetes for a single Deployment - use case: reload

Tags: kubernetes

I reload my process running as a Kubernetes Deployment by exiting 0. Sometimes the restarts may be frequent depending on external factors. It does not affect my application as the restarts are intentional and graceful shutdown happens.

Problem is Kubernetes sees this as a problem and puts my pod into Crashloop. Please suggest how to disable Crashloop in pods.

I am using restart and Kubernetes Deployment as a feature.

Comment: I don't believe that part of the [pod life cycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) can be changed. If you change the `restartPolicy`, you can no longer rely on exiting the process. I assume your process is receiving a remote message to trigger this? You might be able to signal the kube api to do the restart for you, but that adds complexity and security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not managing a long-running process you might want to look at using a Kubernetes job instead of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as `Community Wiki` as good point was mention in comment section by @Matt.

Unfortunately, at this moment changing `CrashLoopBackOff` as this is `Work as Intended` behavior.
As pointed in [Sysdig documentation](https://sysdig.com/blog/debug-kubernetes-crashloopbackoff/) about `CrashLoopBackOff`

> A CrashloopBackOff means that you have a pod starting, crashing, starting again, and then crashing again.

There is an open thread on [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57291) for some `CrashLoopBackoff` changes, which might be useful in the future with scenarios like this, however it's open since `Dec 2017`.

`Restart Policy` as default is set to `Always`, so chaning it won't help.

> The default value is `Always` and the `restartPolicy` only refers to restarts of the containers by the kubelet on the same node (so the restart count will reset if the pod is rescheduled in a different node). Failed containers that are restarted by the kubelet are restarted with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s …) capped at five minutes, and is reset after ten minutes of successful execution.

Good explanation about `Network Policy` differences can be found in [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530946/what-is-the-difference-between-always-and-on-failure-for-kubernetes-restart-poli).

> **Always** means that the container will be restarted even if it exited with a zero exit code (i.e. successfully). This is useful when you don't care why the container exited, you just want to make sure that it is always running (e.g. a web server). This is the default.

> **Failure** means that the container will only be restarted if it exited with a non-zero exit code (i.e. something went wrong). This is useful when you want accomplish a certain task with the pod, and ensure that it completes successfully - if it doesn't it will be restarted until it does.

**As workaround**

You can think about using [Kubernetes jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/), as per @Pythonista answer and depends on your needs you can also use [Kubernetes CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).